How to replace code before transpiling TypeScript code using Rollup. (How to transpile TypeScript code with Private Class Fields to ES5.)
I wont to do
I want to transpile TypeScript code with Private Class Fields to ES5 like when using TypeScript's private identifier.
(I give up one or the other, it will be resolved soon. But I don't want to give up.)
I did
I tried to replace code before transpiling TypeScript code using Rollup.
// ./src/index.mts
export class Foo {
  #foo = 0
  #bar = 'a'
  get foo() {
    return this.#foo
  }
  set foo(value) {
    this.#foo = value
  }
  get bar() {
    return this.#bar
  }
  set bar(value) {
    this.#bar = value
  }
}

// rollup.config.mjs
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
export default {
  input: './src/index.mts',
  output: {
    file: './dist/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    replace({ // Assumption that ' #' and '.#' are not used in strings, regular expressions, etc.
      ' #': ' private _',
      '.#': '._',
      delimiters: ['', '']
    }),
    typescript({compilerOptions: {target: 'es5'}})
  ]
}

result
JavaScript code using WeakMap is output. Not appear to be replaced.
Changing from ' private _' to ' _', same result.
How can I solve what I want?
note
In JavaScript file, expected result is output.
So I see nothing wrong with Rollup replace plugin part.
// rollup.config.mjs
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
export default {
  input: './src/index.mjs',
  output: {
    file: './dist/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    replace({ // Assumption that ' #' and '.#' are not used in strings, regular expressions, etc.
      ' #': ' _',
      '.#': '._',
      delimiters: ['', '']
    })
  ]
}

// ./src/index.mjs (same as ./src/index.mts)
export class Foo {
  #foo = 0
  #bar = 'a'
  get foo() {
    return this.#foo
  }
  set foo(value) {
    this.#foo = value
  }
  get bar() {
    return this.#bar
  }
  set bar(value) {
    this.#bar = value
  }
}


I did it!?
Warnings occurred..., expected results were output.
transformer
// transformer.mjs

import * as ts from 'typescript'

const updatePrivatePropertyDeclaration = (factory, node) => factory.updatePropertyDeclaration(
  node,
  (node.modifiers || []).concat(factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword)),
  factory.createIdentifier(node.name.getFullText().replace(/^#/, '_')),
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined
)

const updatePrivatePropertyAccessExpression = (factory, node) => factory.updatePropertyAccessExpression(
  node,
  node.expression,
  factory.createIdentifier(node.name.getFullText().replace(/^#/, '_'))
)

const isPropertyDeclaration = node => node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration

const isPropertyAccessExpression = node=> node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression

export const transform = context => sourceFile => {
  const visitor = node => (
    isPropertyDeclaration(node) && node.name.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.PrivateIdentifier ?
    updatePrivatePropertyDeclaration(context.factory, node) :
    isPropertyAccessExpression(node) && node.name.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.PrivateIdentifier ?
    updatePrivatePropertyAccessExpression(context.factory, node) :
    ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context)
  )
  return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visitor)
}

export default program => transform

rollup.config
// rollup.config.mjs

import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

import transformer from './transformer.mjs'

export default {
  input: './src/index.mts',
  output: {
    file: './dist/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      compilerOptions: {target: 'es5'},
      transformers: {
        before: [
          {
            type: 'program',
            factory: transformer
          }
        ]
      }
    })
  ]
}

or
// rollup.config.mjs

import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

import {transform} from './transformer.mjs'

export default {
  input: './src/index.mts',
  output: {
    file: './dist/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      compilerOptions: {target: 'es5'},
      transformers: {
        before: [
          transform
        ]
      }
    })
  ]
}

References

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/typescript#transformers
https://ts-ast-viewer.com/
https://github.com/itsdouges/typescript-transformer-handbook
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/compiler/factory/nodeFactory.ts

